# Get attributes for method given by name in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, ravendb

I'm using `ravendb` as storage backend. Since it uses `unit of work` pattern I need to open session, perform actions, save results and close session. I want to keep my code clean and don't call session opening and closing explicitly in each action, so I put this code to `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted` methods, like this:

```cs
    #region RavenDB's specifics

    public IDocumentSession DocumentSession { get; set; }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.DocumentSession = Storage.Instance.OpenSession();
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (this.DocumentSession != null && filterContext.Exception == null)
        {
            this.DocumentSession.SaveChanges();
        }

        this.DocumentSession.Dispose();
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    #endregion
```

But some actions require connection to `ravendb` and come don't. So I've decided to create custom attribute and mark methods need to have DocumentSession opened with it. Here is an example:

```cs
    //
    // GET: /Create

    [DataAccess]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And I stuck. My plan was to retrieve actions' attributes in the `OnActionExecuted` method and if `[DataAccess]` is present, open `DocumentSession`.

In the `OnActionExecuted` I can retrieve action name (method's name) via `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName` statement. But how I can retrieve method's attributes of the given class using reflection?

I found out that it might be `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes` call, but closest I got — I need to have `MemberInfo` object of the method. But how I can get this `MemberInfo` for method given by name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inherit your custom attribute from FilterAttribute, it will have OnActionExecuted and OnActionExecuting methods. And it will be executed before general OnActionExecuted and OnActionExecuting.

Example:

```
public class DataAccessAttribute: FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{       

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
        {
            return;
        }
        var controller = (YourControllerType)filterContext.Controller;
        controller.DocumentSession = Storage.Instance.OpenSession();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
        {
            return;
        }
        var controller = (YourControllerType)filterContext.Controller;
        documentSession = controller.DocumentSession; 
        if (documentSession != null && filterContext.Exception == null)
        {
            documentSession.SaveChanges();
        }

        documentSession.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hm... `DocumentSession` should belong to controller instance. Otherwise I would able to save and retrieve data. Or I need to come up with the way how to perform this.

Comment: You have instance of ControllerBase Controller in filterContext. You can cast it to type of your controller and take any property of it. I update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like answer I've searching for!

Comment: One small thing: calls to `base` are illegal in this case.

Comment: Tested. Works fine! Thank you Kirill!

Answer (score 1):

Why not have your `DataAccess` attribute inherit from [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) so you can put the ActionExecuting/Executed methods on the attribute instead of the Controller?

[Example of how to do it with NHibernate](http://ayende.com/blog/4809/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-what-about-transactions) by using an action filter to set the session on a base controller. It's done using NHibernate, but very similar to what you'd need to do and it's written by Ayende who's one of the RavenDB authors I believe.